# Servlet on Jetty 8 (non embedded!) + Weld for CDI

Tags: servlets, jetty, cdi, weld

I want to deploy a WAR to Jetty 8. The WAR contains a simple servlet that has a dependency injected into it via CDI (Weld).

All the examples/questions I've found online only seem to deal with embedded Jetty - nothing about just using Jetty as an external servlet container.

I've set everything up with the best of my knowledge of how these pieces fit together, but the injection doesn't seem to happen, even when the system says everything is a-ok for injection.

I have a bare **beans.xml** in my META-INF.

My pom.xml, jetty-context.xml + jetty-env (in my WEB-INF), the servlet, the injectee implementation + implementation:

http://pastebin.com/qh7pGCn5

When the war is deployed, everything initially seems ok:

`Mar 08, 2013 3:38:42 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900 1.1.10 (Final)
Mar 08, 2013 3:38:42 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject Use
rTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronousl
y.
Mar 08, 2013 3:38:42 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.jetty.JettyPost72Container in
itialize
INFO: Jetty7 detected, JSR-299 injection will be available in Listeners, Servlet
s and Filters.
init init init init init init init init init init init init init init init!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

...then I get a null pointer when it tries to access the injectee on line 41 of the servlet.

Am I missing something obvious? Weld is telling me everything is good to for the CDI.. but nothing appears there.

edit: I have also tried this with everything aligned to Jetty 7.6.9.v20130131 (which is supported by Weld, according to the documentation)

Cheers, appreciate any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `Greeter` from an overridden Servlet.init() method. This means that the servlet is not yet initialized at that point. From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) -

> Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is being placed into service.
>
> The servlet container calls the init method exactly once after instantiating the servlet. The init method must complete successfully before the servlet can receive any requests.

Now, since you don't declare a scope for your `Greeter` it is automatically of `@Dependent` scope. Therefore, although the `@Dependent` scope is always active, dependent objects' life-cycle is bound to the instance into which they are injected, In other words, they cannot exist by themselves. See this [part](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#dependentcontext) of the CDI specification.

That said, all other normal scopes are only active during the [Sevlet.serice()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) method. Hence, you cannot inject anything until the Servlet is fully initialized. See this [part](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#builtincontexts) of the CDI specification.

Conclusion - try calling your `Greeter` from the service method, which you can only do with an actual request if I'm not mistaken. Hope this helps!